# RSpec test not passing on my users controller `Expected response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a <200: OK>`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

After looking at posts of people with similar error messages, I still can't work out why my RSpec test won't pass. When running my spec I'm getting the following error message:

> > Failures:
>
> 1) UsersController GET #show when a user is not logged in redirects
>   to login
>        Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to(new_user_session_path)
>
> ```
>    Expected response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a <200: OK>
>    Response body:
>  # ./spec/model/user_spec.rb:21:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
> ```
>
> Finished in 0.25988 seconds (files took 5.02 seconds to load) 5
>   examples, 1 failure
>
> Failed examples:
>
> rspec ./spec/model/user_spec.rb:19 # UsersController GET #show when a
>   user is not logged in redirects to login"

---

Here is my user_spec file:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe UsersController, type: :controller do
  let(:user) { User.create!(email: 'test@example.com', password: '1234567890') }

  describe 'GET #show' do

    context 'when a user is logged in' do
        before do
            sign_in user
        end
        it 'loads correct user details' do
            get :show, params: { id: user.id }
            expect(assigns(:user)).to eq user
        end
    end

    context 'when a user is not logged in' do
      it 'redirects to login' do
        get :show, params: { id: user.id }
        expect(response).to redirect_to(new_user_session_path)
      end
    end
  end

end
```

My rails_helper.rb:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
require 'spec_helper'

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
  # Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
  abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
  require 'rspec/rails'
  # Add additional requires below this line. Rails is not loaded until this point!

  # note: require 'devise' after require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'devise'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # For Devise >= 4.1.0
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
  # Use the following instead if you are on Devise <= 4.1.1
  # config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end

  # Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc, in
  # spec/support/ and its subdirectories. Files matching `spec/**/*_spec.rb` are
  # run as spec files by default. This means that files in spec/support that end
  # in _spec.rb will both be required and run as specs, causing the specs to be
  # run twice. It is recommended that you do not name files matching this glob to
  # end with _spec.rb. You can configure this pattern with the --pattern
  # option on the command line or in ~/.rspec, .rspec or `.rspec-local`.
  #
  # The following line is provided for convenience purposes. It has the downside
  # of increasing the boot-up time by auto-requiring all files in the support
  # directory. Alternatively, in the individual `*_spec.rb` files, manually
  # require only the support files necessary.
  #
  # Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

  # Checks for pending migrations and applies them before tests are run.
  # If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # RSpec Rails can automatically mix in different behaviours to your tests
  # based on their file location, for example enabling you to call `get` and
  # `post` in specs under `spec/controllers`.
  #
  # You can disable this behaviour by removing the line below, and instead
  # explicitly tag your specs with their type, e.g.:
  #
  #     RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do
  #       # ...
  #     end
  #
  # The different available types are documented in the features, such as in
  # https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  # Filter lines from Rails gems in backtraces.
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
  # arbitrary gems may also be filtered via:
  # config.filter_gems_from_backtrace("gem name")

end
```

My users_controller:

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show, :index]
    load_and_authorize_resource
  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name)
    end
end
```

And routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout' }

  resources :products do
    resources :comments
  end
  resources :users

  post 'simple_pages/thank_you'

  get 'simple_pages/about'

  get 'simple_pages/contact'

  get 'simple_pages/thank_you'

  get 'simple_pages/index'
    root "simple_pages#landing_page"

    resources :orders, only: [:index, :show, :create, :destroy]

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is due to 2

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show, :index]
```

Your filter is being override by second call to the same. In the second call you have `expect show` which will allow user to access page without login and hence your test will not pass as it is not being redirect to login page. Just remove `before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show, :index]` from controller and it will work for your test.

Comment: If I remove `before_action :authenticate_user!` I still get teh same error message.

Comment: Happy to help. If it worked you can accept the answer.